# simple regex for email address validation

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, email-address

I need a regex to exclude certain characters such as 'ç' and also to check '@' sign is present. Can someone help?

I am using jquery to do client-side validation using the following expression:

```
(/^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/)
```

Comment: May I suggest http://www.regexlib.com, unless you have a regex of your own that you've written and that you need help with?

Comment: `ç` is a legal character in an email address.

Comment: ATM I am using (/^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/) but how do I exclude the character mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, I am aware that it is a legal character but due to system constraints I have to exclude...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chiefly:

```
function isAValidEmailAddress(emailAddress){
     return /^[a-z0-9_\-\.]{2,}@[a-z0-9_\-\.]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,}$/i.test(emailAddress);
}
```

Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax for a better regular expression.